# Add a condition before a success function in AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'd like to create a condition on a success function.

If it doesn't fulfill the requirements, then it should go to the error function.

```js
$(function() {
  var $orders = $('#orders');
  var $name = $('#name');
  var $age = $('#age');

  $('#add-order').on('click', function() {
      var order = {
        name: $name.val(),
        age: $age.val(),
      };

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/api/test.json',
          data: order,
          if (order.name.length > 5 && newOrder.age > 16) {
            success: function(newOrder) {
              $orders.append('<li>name : ' + newOrder.name + ' age :' + newOrder.age + '</li>');
            } else {
              // if name length is not more than 5 and age is less than 17 it will error.
              error: function() {
                alert('error loading orders');
              }
            }
          });
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="orders"></ul>

<p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
<p>age: <input type="text" id="age"></p>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this comment as your Subject says "Add a condition **before** a success function in AJAX". I would delete it but i'll leave it here for future reference

I would suggest you send the data anyway and do your validations from the server. This way the people from the outside won't see the validations and be able to bypass it without the right data.

But if you wish to do it before sending your data the you can use the `beforeSend` function

```
, beforeSend: function() {
    // do validfations here
},
```

a full example using your code would be

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    , url: '/api/test.json'
    , data: order
    beforeSend: function() {
        if (order.name.length <= 5 || newOrder.age <= 16) {
            // display error message here
            return false;
        }
    }, 
    , success: function(newOrder) {
          $orders.append('<li>name : ' + newOrder.name + ' age :' + newOrder.age + '</li>');
        } else {
          // if name length is not more than 5 and age is less than 17 it will error.
          error: function() {
            alert('error loading orders');
          }
    }
});
```

Note there is also a `complete: function() {}` function that you can use after a success

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax() function will perform as follows:

> *Success*: A function to be called if the request succeeds.
>   *Error*: A function to be called if the request fails.

[Source: AJAX Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So, These two will be called based on if the `Ajax` request has succeeded or failed. If it gets a response with a status code of 200, it will be a success. You can customize your callbacks based on the response in this way, as it may be a cleaner way to handle successes and failures individually:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() { //done is the same as success
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {//will run if it fails
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {//will ALWAYS run
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

From what I can understand of your code, you might want to filter your query before you perform the AJAX call. To minimize confusion, I did not use the above syntax:

```
$(function() {
  var $orders = $('#orders');
  var $name = $('#name');
  var $age = $('#age');

  $('#add-order').on('click', function() {
      var order = {
        name: $name.val(),
        age: $age.val(),
      };

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/api/test.json',
          data: order,
          success: function(newOrder) {
            if ($name.val() > 5 && $age.val()){
               $orders.append('<li>name : ' + newOrder.name + ' age :' + newOrder.age + '</li>');
            }
          },
          error: function() {
             alert('error loading orders');
          }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

To even further optimize your code, don't make the AJAX request unless your data fits the criteria of your `if` statement:

```
$(function() {
  var $orders = $('#orders');
  var $name = $('#name');
  var $age = $('#age');

  $('#add-order').on('click', function() {
    if ($name.val() > 5 && $age.val()){
      var order = {
        name: $name.val(),
        age: $age.val(),
      };

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/api/test.json',
          data: order,
          success: function(newOrder) {
             $orders.append('<li>name : ' + newOrder.name + ' age :' + newOrder.age + '</li>');

          },
          error: function() {
             alert('error loading orders');
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert('Name and age did not fit criteria for an order');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`success` and `error` execute depending on whether the ajax call was successful or not. You can define an error function that you can call in the error handler as well as in the success handler when your error condition is fulfilled. You can also check order length before making an unnecessary AJAX request:

```
if (order.name.length < 6) {
  myerrorhandler();
} else {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/test.json',
      data: order,
      success: function(newOrder){
                 if (newOrder.age > 16) {
                   $orders.append('<li>name : '+ newOrder.name +' age :'+ newOrder.age+'</li>');
                  } else { // if age is less than 17
                    myerrorhandler();
                  }
                },
      error:    function(){
                  myerrorhandler();
                }
  });
}
```

And the function:

```
function myerrorhandler() {
   alert('error loading orders');
}
```